# HLS Split and Serve Playlist

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8, hls.js

I want to split and serve a `m3u8` playlist to a `hls.js` client running in a browser. The playlist is big and split and serve is the only option.

When I split and serve till `BigBuckBunny_4000_00004.ts` as given by the playlist below, movie played till that file. `hjs.js` fails to play the next sequence of files, even though the rest of the playlist content was served on a subsequent request.

I have tried to add `m3u8` header, line 1-6 on every request, the effect was same. Whereas the movie play time was updated in this case.

I couldn't understand the behavior of `hls.js` client. Please clarify!

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI=BigBuckBunny.key, IV=0x22725d47cccd5db2834c1f1ec375df73
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
#EXTINF:6.083333,
BigBuckBunny_4000_00000.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
BigBuckBunny_4000_00001.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
BigBuckBunny_4000_00002.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
BigBuckBunny_4000_00003.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
BigBuckBunny_4000_00004.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
BigBuckBunny_4000_00005.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
BigBuckBunny_4000_00006.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
BigBuckBunny_4000_00007.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
BigBuckBunny_4000_00008.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
BigBuckBunny_4000_00009.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: How long is video (duration) and what Target Duration do you use for segmentation?

Comment: Video duration is 3hrs and segment duration is 6 seconds.

Comment: Such playlist is not big. 24 hours videos with target duration 6 seconds work perfectly fine. Most video tech companies provide 4 hours DVR window even with a smaller target duration.